# Sails.js - How to inject a js file to a specific route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, inject

For example, I have a page `/locations/map` which I need to include [Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) library, and include a **.js** file *(e.g. location.js)* specifically for this page only.

I want to inject these 2 files to after `<!--SCRIPTS END-->` this line

Is it possible to do this?

**NOTE: I was using Sails.js v0.10**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sails uses `ejs-locals` in its view rendering, so you can accomplish what you want with blocks.

In your `layout.ejs` file, underneath the `<!--SCRIPTS END-->`, add (for example):

```
<%- blocks.localScripts %>
```

Then in the view you're serving at `/locations/map`, call the block with your script tag, for example:

```
<% block('localScripts', '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>') %>
```

As an alternative, you could put the `<!--SCRIPTS-->` and `<!--SCRIPTS END-->` tags in the `<head>` of your layout, and then add your view-specific scripts directly into your view rather than using blocks.  This is a fine option if you don't mind waiting for those linked scripts to load before your page content is displayed.

Comment: Wow~it works. but is it possible to inject in `MapController` rather than in view?

Comment: In your controller action, you could set `res.locals.gmapScript='<script src="...etc..."'` and then in the view do `<%- block('localScripts', gmapScript) %>`...

Comment: That means no matter how, `<%- block('localScripts', gmapScript) %>` this line must put in view?

Comment: Yes, the only way to add text to your view (besides using the linker, i.e. the `<!--SCRIPTS-->` tag) is by putting it in the template.  The benefit of this is that you always open that view file and have an idea of what's in there.  If you started adding text to the view in your controller before sending a response, it would be a lot harder to debug!

Comment: The initial solution (<%- blocks.localScripts %>) works but everything I place in the block appears two times - Once where it is declared in the view and the other time is in the layout where blocks.localScripts is defined. Should this happen? (I solved it by adding the block in the view in html comments)

Comment: It should be `<% block(...` instead of `<%- block(...` to prevent populate the contents twice.  Full sample: `<% block('localScripts', '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>') %>`

Answer (score 13):

[Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345484/scott-gress)'s answer is the proper way to insert non-global JS into a specific view. Just a little comment, though: the `block` call from the view **should not have the dash**. It should be as follows:

`<% block('localScripts', '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>') %>`

Both calls will work, but using the dash makes the insertion twice; once the view is loaded and previous to the layout render, and then once again when the view is inserted in the rendered base layout. This leads not only to inserting/running unnecessarily twice the same code but also to errors that break your JS code if the inserted script depends on libraries that you have in your base layout (e.g. jQuery, Backbone).

EJS interprets the magic `<%-` as "insert unescaped". So, -*I guess*- what this is doing is calling the `block()` function, which returns our HTML `<script>` tag. This is replaced where the magic was called but also is executing the `block()` function inside of it, which is executing the layout block `localScripts` replacement.

On the other hand, `<%` means "instruction". I.e., just run this JS piece of code, which is not echoed to the view where is called.

Answer (score 4):

I discover other way to do that

In **MapController.js**

```
// you can add as many as you like
res.locals.scripts = [
  '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
];
return res.view();
```

In **layout.ejs**

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->

<!-- Loop through all scripts that passed from controller -->
<% if (scripts) { %>
    <% for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) { %>
        <script src="<%- scripts[i] %>"></script>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I think this might be the solution Im after to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120430/inject-javascript-to-specific-view-route-in-sailsjs-after-all-the-global-javascr/27121109?noredirect=1#comment42743390_27121109. May I ask do we have a way to populate the scripts even nicer?

Comment: @hjbolide My sailsjs project has been suspended, if you found another way to make it nicer, go ahead. I'm now doing more ios project, can't help you much in this

Comment: it's very very appreciated, and my project is now using your solution, I love it ! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

This method allows flexibility to locally serve js files from any page and also prevent any reference errors caused by dependencies.

In **pipeline.js** insert **'!js/local/*.js** at the bottom of **jsFilesToInject** like so:

```
var jsFilesToInject = [

// Load sails.io before everything else
'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

// Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
'js/dependencies/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

// All of the rest of your client-side js files
// will be injected here in no particular order.
'js/**/*.js',

//Ignore local injected scripts
'!js/local/*.js' 

];
```

Create a **local** folder inside the **/assets/js** folder ie **/assets/js/local/**. Place any locally injected scripts in here.

In your master view ejs ie **layout.ejs** insert **<%- blocks.localScripts %>** below the SCRIPTS block like this:

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/popper.min.js"></script>
<!--SCRIPTS END--> 
<%- blocks.localScripts %>
```

In your local ejs view (eg. homepage.ejs) insert your **localScripts** block like this:

```
<% block('localScripts', '<script src="/js/local/homepage.js"></script>') %>
```

sails v0.12.14

**EDIT**
**Is this still relevant for Sails v1.0?**

My answer is a resounding **YES** and in my earlier answer I lacked explaining how to get the most out of the Grunt pipeline like clean, coffee, concat, uglify etc... when going into production.

The trick here is to make a local file (there should only be one per page) as small as possible.

- Group and name specific your function calls
- Save functions as separate files for easy maintenance and group them into folders.
- Group bindings and any initialising of global variables into a couple of functions like `initThisPageVariables()` and `initThisPageBindings()` so that Grunt can crunch these later.
- Set a master function call to run your app `startThisPageApp()`

Then simply calling the few functions from your local (master) file to get things rolling.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

   initThisPageVariables();
   initThisPageBindings();

   $(window).on("resize", function(){
      initThisPageVariables();
   }).resize();

   startThisPageApp(); 

});
```

Comment: Took me a while to understand the logic,but it is genius : "'!js/local/*.js' " stops sails from loading js from this location.  
<%- blocks.localScripts %> loads code, pointing to the local script if told so. 
<% block('localScripts', '<script src="/js/local/homepage.js"></script>') %> tells which file should be loaded. Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: The above answer is correct and I just wanted to point out that you can load css via, ` <%- blocks.localStyles %>` and js via `<%- blocks.localScripts %>`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question by I discovered another option.

File:

> *config\routes.js*

Code:

```
'/': 'HomeController.StartHome'
```

I set *StartHome* function in *HomeController* responsible for managing '/' route.

File:

> *api\controllers\HomeController.js*

Code:

```
StartHome: function(req, res) {

    var template_data = {
        "data" : {
            "view_name" : "home_view"
        }

    }

    res.view('home_view', template_data)
}
```

Here, I created an object with some data which is passed to EJS template(to client).

File:

> *views\layout.ejs*

Code:

```
<% if (data["view_name"] === "home_view") { %>
<script src="script_for_home_view.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

In my layouts.ejs I created if statement which "enables" script tag depending on on the view I am currently on.

This is how I handle this. I hope it's clear for you.

Sails 0.12.4