# Inject javascript to specific view/route in Sailsjs after all the global javascripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Recently I have been trying to build a really simple chat app using sailsjs, the app has only 3 pages, each page has different sets of reference data that will feed twitter typeahead js, what I intend to do is like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $modalLayer = $(JST['assets/templates/generic/modal.html']({}));
    $modalLayer.appendTo("body").modal('show');

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.request('/chat/references', {}, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            bindTypeAhead(data);
            $modalLayer.modal('hide');
    });

});
```

For different page I have different logic, so need to be separated into different javascript files.

What I have tried were:

- using  tag in pagea.ejs and pageb.ejs
- using <%- block('localScripts', 'SCRIPT_TAG') %>

Both approaches made the script come before all the javascript injections defined in pipeline.js, thus socket.io becomes undefined.

Some solutions I found on stackoverflow I read was to move the javascript injections to "<head>", but I think this is a hacky way to go, I dont really want to break sailsjs convention.

Could anybody have a nice way of doing it?

Many thanks.

The sails I'm using is versioned 0.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use a layout template and a <%-scripts%> tag to designate where child pages scripts should go.

Comment: Does it come after all the injections? The layout.ejs is by default populated by sailsjs itself, I don't have a separate one, could you please show me how you did it?

Comment: In your pages you can use a <% layout('layoutName') -%> tag to designate which layout to use or modify layout.ejs in the views folder.

You can place your <%-scripts%> tag after the:
<!--TEMPLATES-->

<!--TEMPLATES END-->
<!--SCRIPTS-->

<!--SCRIPTS END-->

Comment: does that mean we need to create a specific layout for each page we want to have special js file?
According to the doc in config/view.js, layouts serve as top level HTML templates. That means we will have duplicate code.